# Windows 10 y sus complicaciones a la hora de codificar

Tags: windows, lista

quisiera saber si alguien que tenga el tiempo y las ganas de enlistar las complicaciones que conlleva empezar a codificar desde un ordenador con windows 10.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: https://www.Microsoft.com/Learn

Answer (score 1):

No considero que se tengan mayores complicaciones al desarrollar en windows 10.
Quizás dependiendo de lo que se desarrolle, el sistema operativo podría ser una limitante (Por ejemplo desarrollar para IOS en windows).
De lo contrario y si la plataforma o el lenguaje de desarrollo lo permite, no tendrías ningún inconveniente estés en windows o en otro sistema operativo.

Comment: Preguntas basadas en opiniones no se deben responder